# Pause IntentService based on connectivity (Queue Intents)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, internet-connection

After consulting Stackoverflow a lot I found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401196/2440358

Now I'm already using an IntentService which is handling the communication with the server and I've implemented a BroadcastReceiver which is looking for the current connectivity state.

**IntentService:**

```
public class CommunicationService extends IntentService {

public CommunicationService() {
    super(CommunicationService.class.getName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String kind = intent.getExtras().getString("kind");
    if ("LocationUpdate".equals(kind)) {
        // send current Location to the server
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    checkConnectionState(context);
}

public static boolean checkConnectionState(final Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommunicationService.class);
    intent.putExtra("kind", "");

    if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // start service
        context.startService(intent);
        return true;
    } else {
        // stop service
        context.stopService(intent);
        return false;
    }
   }
 }
```

That's all working like a charm, but I don't know how to bring those two together like mentioned in the link above. I really would like to use that mentioned automatic queueing of the IntentService without.

Is there an easy way to make use of the IntentServices queueing and make it queue everything until the connectivity comes back?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

**Edit:** Now I solved it in a kinda dirty hack. The Application itself has a queue now, where the intents are added to in case they go wrong (internet connection loss during execution) or when there is no internet connection at all. The intents from that queue will be started again in the broadcastreceivers onReceive() when internet connection is available. I hope it helps someone ;)